# Dynamically load server side data into slickgrid using ajax

Tags: php, slickgrid

I'm in the situation where I have many thousands or database records. I cannot load all these records in one go due to memory constraints.

So what I intend to do is, request 1000 records using an ajax request and loading this into `slickgrid` and then progressively load the other records in the same way in the background until all the data is loaded (lets say 50,000 records).

The first 1000 records should be loaded and subsequent records added in the background. This way the user can initially start filtering, sorting etc even if the full dataset has not finished loading.

I have looked at the ajax example:

> http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html

However, it doesn't address my dynamic loading requirement.

My question is can this be done easily and if so what are the slickgrid functions that I would need to consider.

Comment: How many records are you talking about? Are you using SlickGrid's DataView? If you have more than 50,000 records then your server should be responsible for filtering, sorting, paginating; in which case the AJAX example should work for you.

Comment: @idbehold The fact is slickgrid can handle very large datasets and thus my reasoning is to attempt to not use the server for some of the tasks you suggest. Filtering the dataset I will do on the server but sorting probably not. So back to my requirement...

Comment: Are you using the DataView?

Comment: @idbehold Yes I probably will use this although my data doesn't have an id column so I'm currently using data (json). I have found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slickgrid/6R7WPHp_L5U wich looks promising

Comment: I would be interested in implementing that too, if you have a working concept please post it :)

Answer (score 0):

First response

```
dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({});
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(yourjsondata);            
dataView.endUpdate();
```

load with the first 1000 record

Since you don't have an id column you can just iterate over the response and add an uuid or just increment a counter and add that I also don't have an id and that's the way I am handling it

All other ajax response

```
dataView.beginUpdate();

for(var i = 0;  i < yourjsondata.length; i++) {
    dataView.setItem(yourjsondata[i]);            
}

dataView.endUpdate();
```

I would highly recommend doing all the data retrieval for all ajax response
other than the first in a web worker so you don't block the ui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

You will have to use vanilla js to make ajax requests no jQuery. In you worker just build an object array and then on the last responses post it back to the main thread

```
self.postMessage(yourobjectarray);
```

Note I have this all working but is not open source. Can share more of the code snippets but can't post the whole thing